# Design pattern for implementing PHP search filter form

Tags: php, search, filter, structure

I am implementing a filter in a search function on a website written in PHP.

My goal is to keep this manageable, since the project will grow in size a lot in the upcoming time. Right now the search page has a  with some input fields, and php checks if the form is submitted by checking if the name of the forms  button is inside the $_POST array. Located on the right side of this search page, there is a list of the actual search results, the output of a foreach loop over a list of items printed to the screen. To make it more clear I've written some code to explain what it does, and also shows what I tried to come up with myself:

```
    <?php
    $arrayToDisplay = array(
            array("id"=>0,"name"=>"first","lastname"=>"last"),
            array("id"=>1,"name"=>"first","lastname"=>"last"),
    );

    $acceptedName = "";


    if(isset($_POST['buttonName'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
            $acceptedName = sanitize($_POST['name']);
        }
    }
?>

<form>
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="buttonName">
</form>

<?php


    foreach($arrayToDisplay as $person) {
            if(exists($acceptedName) && $acceptedName != "") {
                if($person["name" == $acceptedname) {
                    echo $person["id"]."  ".$person["name"];
                }       
            }
            else {
                echo $person["id"]."  ".$person["name"];
            }

    }
?>
```

This can work on one value, filter by name. But eventually these person objects will have almost 50 properties, and the search filter has to not only be able to filter the list by name, but all kinds of person properties. This solution is unmaintainable.

Is there an existing design pattern, that one might use in such a situation?

Comment: Don't mix html and php code. Use some template engine (twig advised).

Comment: I can see how that could improve maintainability. I'm still confused on how I would relate the search filter fields and the actual list items though. Is there maybe a good object oriented way to represent them in code?

Comment: If you want to have your search filter values combined with an “AND”, then you have to loop over all of them for each person. So it might make sense to capture those in an array to begin with. `$filters = ['name' => NULL, 'lastname' => NULL, …]` Then you loop over your post values, and see what corresponding values were submitted. Replace the NULL with that value then. Afterwards, you can loop over $filters in your output section, and for all entries where the value is not NULL, you have to check the corresponding property of your current person.

Comment: Do you want to use a single text box to search all columns or use individual text boxes to search specific columns?

Comment: @waterloomatt individual boxes to search for specific colums, kind of like in the example, but think more boxes and more values in the list :)

Comment: So there isn't a design pattern per se to handle this scenario, but there are things you can do to save the repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches to this problem and some people argue that you can/should type out each form element and its corresponding handler because it'll be easier to maintain if you want to use text boxes, select lists, radio buttons etc. That said, you mentioned simply using text boxes so here's a way to use a single array to drive the entire application.

- You didn't mention if you were planning on using SQL to drive your search, so I made the assumption you will be using it.
- You can use a single array to drive both your HTML form and the query that will be generated by the incoming values.

---

```
<?php

// This array will drive your form and your query.
$columns = [
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'email',
    'address_1',
    'address_2',
    'city'
];

// The form was submitted.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // Match posted data to the `$columns` array and filter out any empty values.
    $postedData = array_filter(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($columns)));

    // We have at least 1 search criteria to use.
    if (!empty($postedData)) {

        // Generate a list of columns for a WHERE clause. Ex. [`address_1 LIKE ?`, `name LIKE ?`]
        $terms = array_map(function ($val) {
            return "$val LIKE ? ";
        }, array_keys($postedData));

        // Generate a list of values wrapped in percent signs. Ex. [`123 King St.`, `%tony%`]
        $values = array_map(function ($val) {
            return "%$val%";
        }, $postedData);

        // Change this to `AND ` if needed.
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' . implode('OR ', $terms);

        // Just showing you what the generated query and data looks like.
        var_dump([
            $query,
            array_values($values)
        ]);

        // Finally, use them to drive your query.
        // $sql = $connection->prepare($query);
        // $sql->execute(array_values($values));
    }
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $column; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $column; ?>">
        </label>

        <br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Sample Output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstname LIKE ? OR email LIKE ? ' (length=59)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '%Tony%' (length=6)
      1 => string '%tony@email.com%' (length=16)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am actually using a soap api in the background, but it could just as well have been mysql :)
This seems like a manageable way to solve my issue, so I'll select this as the best answer. Thank you.